# AngularJS: Calling a Method in a Controller from a Directive, and Passing Parameters

Tags: angularjs-directive

I’m new to AngularJS, and I have an app (v 1.2.26) which contains a directive to handle reading files when the user selects them via an HTML file input.  The directive calls a service which parses the files, and then needs to update a view with tabular data from the parsed files.  All of this is working except for updating the view.

In order to update the view, I have a controller method which I would like to call from the directive.

**The first question**: is this a good way to update a view with data from a directive (i.e. passing data to a controller)?

**Second question** (assuming this is a valid approach): calling the method in the controller using the following code doesn’t work.  What am I doing wrong?

The app module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

The controller (in same file as app module):

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.updatePanel = function(myData) {
    // this never gets called:
    console.log('you rang?');
  };
});
```

The file-handling directive (in a different file):

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('fileBrowser', ['myDataService', function (myDataService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><div><input type="file" class="btn btn-default"/></div></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      var container = element.children();
      var bindFileControlChange = function () {
      // [snip] read the file (this works)
      //...

      // pass the file to the myDataService (this works):
      var myData = myDataService.parse(myFileContent);
      // call the controller method - this doesn't work:
      scope.$apply('updatePanel(myData)');
      //...
      };
     }
   };
 }
]);
```

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: You're adding function `updatePanel` to controller instead of to $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first question:** It's not wrong. If you can use your directive's controller, you might feel more comfortable maintaining a factory which includes your tabulated data. I know I used the link when I made my file browser directive, so I suspect this is not an option for you (but I'm not certain).

**Second question:** Using your example, I think you want to pass in a function. For this, I would recommend using an isolated scope variable, for example:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('fileBrowser', ['myDataService', function (myDataService) {
    return {
        // ...
        scope: {
            updatePanel: "="
        },
        // ...
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // ...
            scope.updatePanel(myData); // Call this whenever
            // ...
        }
    };
});
```

And the html:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <file-browser update-panel="updatePanel"></file-browser>
</div>
```

Let me know if that suits your needs. If not, I'll try to come up with a better answer.